# Geometry Nodes — place instances to line archway

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I'm trying to line this archway with a single line of "LEDs" using geometry nodes. I have a vertex group that isolates the arch (see screenshot) and it ALMOST does what I want it to, except it's adding extra instances on edges adjacent to, and not within my vertex group. I'm sure I could probably get what I want by just adding actual points to my model on the straight vertical parts of the arch and just doing a simple Instances on Points but was trying to avoid having to add geometry just for decoration.

Even more awesome would be a solution that actually adds instances equidistant around the whole arch rather than still sticking them directly on the points on the curved section (that's what I was attempting to do in the first place).

Thanks for having a look!

[image: Vertex group]

[image: Output with extra instances]

[image: Node setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are interpolated between the value of (I assume) 1 at the vertices that are part of the vertex group, and 0 to the other side of the edge. The selection is however a boolean operation, so any value > 0 will not be discarded. If you don't want the curve to be sampled, add a math operation to remove the interpolation.

eg

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gorgious! That was it. Brilliant.